# $pull and $push Query in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

MongoDB supports $pull and $push query to remove or add an element into an array. Can a similar type of query present in the elastic search which used to add or remove element from array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use scripts for this, and update using update_by_query API.

```
{ 
    "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.<name_of_array>.add(params.<name_of_variable>)",
    "params": {"<name_of_variable>": 1}
  },
  "query": {
    // specify the query if want to apply on filtered documents.
}
```

Comment: how I pull data from array like $pull in mongodb?